# PHP echo not printing

Tags: php, mysql

Am facing a weird issue in my PHP coding...let me describe the purpose of my PHP code

1. Read Cell Value from excel and upload it in a MySQL table
2. Read EACH value from MySQL table and fetch data from an external source
3. Store the data in table fetched from external source
4. Echo the process is done
5. Echo a link to display the result

The code is perfectly working fine but when the Excel row size is big then Point 1,2,3 is working but 4,5 is not displaying

There is no error no warning...

Am just clueless why this issue is happening

Am attaching the code snippet below:

```
<?php

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

error_reporting(0);

session_start();

require_once("index11.php");

require_once("simple_html_dom.php");

include('ganon.php');

ini_set('max_execution_time', 1200);






$val2 = $_SESSION['$val2'];




if($_SESSION['$val8'] == "mu")
{

if($_SESSION['$val2'] == "fr")

{

//echo "MU for FR";


$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "****");


if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("DB")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}


$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT EANcode from test WHERE timestamp = DATE( NOW( ) ) and EAncode <> ''";



$result = mysql_query($sql);
$a = 0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

foreach ($row as $b) 

 { 
$ean = $b;

$url = "WWW.URL.COM" .$ean;

$html = file_get_html($url);


$link=$html->find('a[class=webtrekk]');

$link1 = $link[4] -> href;


$link2 = "WWW.URL.COM" .$link1;

$html = file_get_dom($link2);


$i = 0;

foreach($html('tr') as $rowdata) {
        $name = '';
        $test1 = '';

       foreach($rowdata('a[class="test1"]') as $d) {
            $name = $d('img', 0)->alt;

$name2 = mysql_real_escape_string($name);
$arr = explode("-", $name2, 2);
$name1 = $arr[0];


        }      

foreach($rowdata('td[class="test1"]') as $d) {
            foreach($d('span[class="test1"]') as $d2) {
                $test1 = $d2->getPlainText();
            }
        }      

if(!$test1 == "")
{
$i = $i + 1;

$now = new DateTime();

$dt = $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

mysql_select_db("DB", $conn);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `DB`.`tab_fr` (`pos`, `ean`, `prod_url`, `prod_compttr`, `prod_test1`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('$i', '$ean','$link2','$name1','$test1', '$dt')";

mysql_query($sql) or die('Error, insert query failed' . mysql_error());




}
    }


}      

}
flush();
usleep(300000);
$msg = "Query op Test.fr succesvol afgerond"; 
echo $msg ."<br/>" ;

}


if($_SESSION['$val2'] == "fr")
{
$v2 = "Test.fr,";
}
else
{
$v2 = "";
}


if($_SESSION['$val2'] == "fr")
{

echo "<a href=10d2.php>cLICK HERE ".$v2."</a>" ."<br/>";

}
}

?>
```

This is happening because of the timeout issue encountered in the code can anybody help me how to continue coding after time out.

Comment: Please paste your code so that we can see how its done and maybe help you on the correct path

Comment: The end of point 3 is not working. Otherwise the echo of point 4 would be there.

Comment: @FranzHolzinger this code is working for smaller rows of test table but when am uploading huge rows then this echo message is not working

Comment: You did not use the `flush();`after the latest `echo "<a href=10d2.php>cLICK HERE ".$v2."</a>" ."<br/>";`. So the output of the echo is not written to the screen but it hangs in an internal buffer.

Comment: @FranzHolzinger...no even after using flush() after this didn't work

Answer (score 0):

When a large number of data is being processed then it may cause a situation equivalent to infinite loop. You see data insertion is success in database but it is not finished. So you have to find a trick to avoid this infinite looping execution.

Hints: break the entire loop into 3 or two.

Comment: How to break the loop if there is any infinite loop

Comment: let us consider your loop is look like: for(i=0;i<$raw;$i++) now you can break this for loop into two as follows:
for(i=0;i<$raw/2;$i++) --- (1)
for(i=$raw/2;$i<$raw;$i++) ---(2). set some delay between these two for loop. Got it?